# Excel macro clicking on a cell unhides the row below

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a table in which certain rows are hidden by default. In one column I have a cell called "Add a row". Clicking on this cell runs a macro that unhides the row below. For example, let's say that every 10th row in the table is hidden (rows 10, 20, 30 etc. are hidden). When I click on cell B9, I want row 10 to be unhidden. Then, when I click on cell B19 I want row 20 to be unhidden etc.
I generated the following code for every single cell:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then  
  Rows("10").Select  
  Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False  
  Range("A10").Select  
End If
```

The problem is that I have to repeat it thousands of times so this procedure becomes too large and Excel does not perform it.
So, I was wondering if it is possible to make a macro the unhides only the row below the cell that was clicked on. Is there a way to click on cell *B(n-1)* and to unhide row *n*? I hope that someone could give a hand with this code! :)

Comment: Selection.offset might get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following, it will check if the row below is hidden, and if it is, it will unhide it after you DoubleClick on the cell above in Column B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

My previous answer would work with a Double-Click, but the answer below will work with a single click on the cell above the row you wish to unhide:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    If Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Xabier! Your answer was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row Mod 10 = 9 Then  'check if the remainder when dividing the row number by 10 is equal to nine
        Rows(Target.Row + 1).Hidden = False 'unhide row below selection
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Franz, for this idea!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to publish the result I got with the help of Xabier and Franz. It works perfectly well!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim N As Integer 'how much times the pattern of rows occurs
Dim A As Integer 'which rows to be hidden

'To unhide rows
'The step to repeat the pattern is 16

For N = 1 To 100
    For A = 16 To 24
        If Target.COLUMN = 11 And Target.Row = A + (N - 1) * 16 Then
            If Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden Then Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            If Rows(Target.Row + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Cells(Target.Row + 1, 1).Select
        End If
    Next A
Next N
End Sub
```